# Find out what HTML elements are forcing the page/block/section to be wide/tall

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change an HTML page (with lots of CSS). There is a `<table>` that is 'too wide'. I can't see why it is being wide. One of the subnodes of it must have some sort of `width: $A_BIG_NUMBER;` css rule that is make it wide, which then propigates up and makes the whole thing wide.

My usual approach is to manually look at all the elements (or ones I think responsible) to try to find this css rule.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 25):

I run into these "mystery" width issues quite a bit - especially when trying to wrangle an open-source theme where I'm not the author of most of the code.

Try adding some wireframes to your CSS.  Use this in **addition** to using a developer web inspector to find the culprit (safari, IE, chrome all now come with developer tools out of the box, firebug for firefox).

```
body { margin: 30px; }
/* Optional: Add some margin to the body to add space and 
see where your offending elements cross the line */

body * { border: 1px solid red; }
/* add a border to all other elements on the page */

body * { outline: 1px solid red; }
/* Alternate: add an outline  to all elements on the page. Won't effect box model */

div#offending-area * { outline: 1px solid red; }
/* If you've got some idea about where the issue is, drill down further than the body tag */
```

Comment: Good tip. Not seen the `body * ...` trick before which helped me spot an offending element in about 5 seconds on a large page.

Comment: Worked for me, too. That, and searching for `width: A_BIG_NUMBER` as OP suggested yielded `body { min-width: 600; }` lurking in my css. Lesson/pseudo-answer: don't be too proud to consider the obvious answer.

Comment: very nice trick. I used it even with margin: 0px; and helped me to find which element has extra width. Thanks!

Comment: Great tip. Thanks.

Comment: I prefer to use `outline: 1px solid red;` as it doesn't affect the box model. All of your document elements remain where they'd normally be instead of moved slightly by the border.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Chromium, just right-click, select "Check Element" (or whatever, its "Element überprüfen" in the german version). Afterwards an "inspector" opens. There you can select the table tag. On the right you'll find a list with recognized CSS-statements incl. the filenames. (It's a bit like Firebug for Firefox, just much faster.)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the 'Element Inspector', however that still involves a lot of manual checking, since I have to go through all the sub-elements. Is there not some extension that shows the sizes?

Comment: @Rory If you mouse-over the tags within the inspector view, the elements are pretty highlighted, so one can see at a glance, what are their dimensions. There is also a "Metrics"-tab below the styles-view in the right panel of the inspector.

Comment: Yeah the metrics is good for seeing the size of certain elements (I've also been looking at the 'Computer Style'), however I still need to manually go over all elements.

Comment: Gnn. *outofbettersolutionshere* Use `overflow:hidden` on the <TD> ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This was the very good article for finding out the element which is overflowed in the website. The javascript code below is for that,

```
var docWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;

[].forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('*'),
  function(el) {
    if (el.offsetWidth > docWidth) {
      console.log(el);
    }
  }
);
```

Check out this link,
https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to open the debugger/inspector (`Ctrl-Shift-I` in Chrome) and then start deleting elements via the `Elements` tab. Then watch for when the page "jumps into place" (= is no longer too wide). When that happens you know you just deleted the offending element :)